# can I use fall down with slip?

Tags: phrases

Someone spitted the soup on th ground, so I slipped and fell down.
Is 'fall down' followed by 'slip' necessary?

Comment: It does help paint the complete picture. You could slip and manage not to fall, you know.

Comment: A) Here and in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/250812/24489) it appears that you are confusing *spit* with *spill* -- you should look these words up. B) In your example *slip* is followed by *fall down*, not the other way around. C) You may slip without falling down if you are agile, so if you want to communicate that you actually fell you must say that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Not "spitted" - "spat".  Someone *spat* on the ground, and I slipped *in it* and fell down.  Your falling down doesn't happen every time someone spits, so you have to make the connection between the spit and the slip.  Since you can slip without falling down, it's fine to mention the falling. There is some acceptable elipsis here, because the full formation would be :"Someone spat on the ground and I slipped *in the spit* and fell down". A little kid might put it like that.  However, in adult speech, the spit is assumed to have been mentioned enough already.

Comment: "the spit is assumed to have been mentioned enough already." Certainly has!

Comment: Reminds me of the Limerick: *There was a young man of Darjeeling, Who travelled by bus to Ealing, The sign on the door, Said, 'don't spit on the floor'; So he carefully spat on the ceiling.*