# Is food "spitted" or "sprinkled"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences

> Be careful. Don't bump the waiter holding the food. Otherwise hot food will be *spitted*/*sprinkled* over you.

Which is the most appropriate and common verb?
What is the difference in meaning between "spitted" and "sprinkled"?
Is there a better verb that means to accidentally *throw* hot food?

Comment: I think you mean "Spill/Spilled." Both "food spitted" and "food sprinkled" are grammatically unfit in your context.

Comment: @Jokaec, try not to thank others in the comments. Of course, you could tell them that you used the advice and it helped a lot :)

Comment: Both "spit" and "sprinkle" are grammatical.  But they have meanings other than "spill".

Comment: Based on your errors, you probably should be in [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: It's "holding", not "holing".  "Spit" means to spew out of your mouth.  "Sprinkle" means to scatter about like raindrops.  In the above context "spilled" is the correct term.  (And it would generally be either "spilled on you" or "spilled all over you", not "spilled over you".)

Comment: Many verbs may be suitable in this situation, depending on the amount, consistency, and distribution of the food that you think will come into contact with the diner. Among the options are _spilled_, _slopped_, _sloshed_, scattered, splattered_, and _spattered_. It is also common to frame the phrase as "...or you'll be ________ with hot food," in which case such verbs  as _doused_, _flooded_,  _inundated_, _covered_, _coated_, and _begrimed_ are additional options.

Comment: @ws2 - Why do you not fix your spelling error?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I haven't the points.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for being your usual kind self and correcting my spelling. I have been out all day. It is England in June, the darling buds are in flower, the air's as rich as Chianti wine, - and the sun is shining.

Comment: @Mrstupid could you please post an answer :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Done (:

Comment: Meat can be *spitted* in the sense of being mounted on a spit to be spit-roasted, though of course that isn't the meaning being asked about here.

Answer (score 1):

1) "[Spill/Spilled](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spill)" means to cause or allow (liquid) to flow over the edge of its container, especially unintentionally. This is the most appropriate and common verb.
**Example:**

> I place the mugs on a small wooden tray and carry it out to the divan, trying not to **spill** the hot liquid.

2) "[Spit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spit)" means to eject saliva/food/liquid forcibly from one’s mouth, sometimes as a gesture of contempt or anger. Whereas, "[sprinkle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sprinkle)" means to scatter or pour (small drops or particles of a substance) over an object or surface.
**Example:**

> I accidentally **sprinkled** too much pepper on the pizza, so I had to **spit** it when I ate it (as it got too spicy).

3) Some better verb that means to accidentally "throw" food (as @SvenYargs suggested):

- [Splattered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/splatter)
- [Sloshed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slosh)
- [Spattered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spatter?q=spattered)